# Google Image search by URL - "Find more like this one" button

Tags: image, google-image-search

I have a gallery of images on my website.  Under each one, I'd like to have a link that says "Find more like this one".  This link would automatically give Google Image Search the image url and return to the user a google search gallery of images like the one they clicked.

To know what I mean by Google Image search by URL, go here and click the camera icon: http://images.google.com/

I haven't really found anything in the deprecated API, and I looked at the way google does it itself, and it seems the submit button is intercepted by obfuscated javascript (even though the form html is of the GET request format).

So I'm at a bit of a loss, not sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is what you need:
http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=

followed by the URL to each of your images on your gallery.

Example:
http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png

I came across your question after suffering a similar problem. I don't have a gallery, I just dislike sharing my browser/computer/personal identity with Google, thus I use Noscript.

When searching for the URL of an image (without clicking the JS obfuscated button), above the results, says thus:
"For matching images, try search by image"

and "Search by image" is a clicky link.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Wow!  Excellent answer.  I never thought of Noscript, but it would make sense that it would lead you to the answer with Google's widespread support.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there an url for json response like http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/...?

Comment: As of Nov 2022, this link does not work anymore. For all who stumble upon this post in search for a new solution please see the [answer of pureth in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73939580/8574452)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following works: http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=your+query

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, that would be a regular text query.  I'm searching for a query by image (url)

Comment: Right. I understand what you mean now.