# Google image search: Link parameter for similar image URL?

Tags: google-image-search

I want to create a link to start a google image search for "happy kitten" with related images to http://s21.postimg.org/3vi73y0c6/funny_cats_wallpaper_gallery_12.jpg

Normal text search:

https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&tbm=isch&q=happy+kitten

When I use "search by image" and add the URL, a cryptic session ID is used and the sent request is:

https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=http%3A%2F%2Fs21.postimg.org%2F3vi73y0c6%2Ffunny_cats_wallpaper_gallery_12.jpg&btnG=Search+by+image&image_content=&filename=

But the error reads that the URL is not public.

How would I create such an URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct URL for Google Image search by Image is:

```
http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=YOUR_HOSTED_URL
```

Comment: Works: `http://images.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=YOUR_HOSTED_URL&q=YOUR_KEYWORDS`

Comment: As of Nov 2022, this link does not work anymore. For all who stumble upon this post in search for a new solution please see the [answer of pureth in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73939580/8574452)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out http://www.google.com/images?q=word of course instead of word you should type in your search word (or words with + in between), for your example

http://www.google.com/images?q=happy+kitten