# google image search by image file(Not URL)

Tags: google-image-search

I've looked around, this question has been asked before but i would like to know if it was possible to do so, maybe without using an API, or using another search-engine.

I would like to check the web for images, by searching with an image.

Is there any way to do so, if so can anybody point me in the right direction, i just can't seem to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so?

https://www.google.nl/search?tbm=isch&hl=nl&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=989&q=YourImageURL_Here

Or just drag the image in the search bar of google.

anyways, look at this post
[Google image search: How do I construct a reverse image search URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584808/google-image-search-how-do-i-construct-a-reverse-image-search-url)

Comment: www.google.co.kr/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiv5agdY_1aa3DzrdhJEQ9ZQ9Q2x9OL8FSMWG4Nl8jQuqF9wjTHb7pDGbZu6sX9LS9p-8J4zBJFXJB-..... like this. This url is result of image search by image.. tbs=sbi:HERE IS MY IMAGE THAT ENCODED CODE

Answer (score 3):

Update: This is now supported natively in Chrome. You can right click and image and choose "Search Google for Image."

This [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-by-image-by-google/dajedkncpodkggklbegccjpmnglmnflm) is the best way. The tool is native to Google Chrome.

Right click to search by image URL. No copying and pasting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use google search by image. Look at this http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html

Answer (score 0):

this is the direct link which work as of now. But not necessarily for forever.

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=YOUR_IMAGE_URL
```