# Google images api

Tags: jquery, image, api

i need to search images on Google images by url, all of this i need to do on jQuery. How it will look: i set image url and script return images urls and titles. But i have a problem, in google api i not found how i can run search by image url. I see https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=Google this, but in api nothing say about use image url.
Then i hope i can load simple google image search, and substitute in google search image url my image url, but Google encoding image url's.
Please help. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Don't forget the version `v=1.0` in the QueryString or you will get nothing in return: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=Google

Comment: It does not matter as long as I can not search for a URL

Comment: What do you mean by url? The response includes a `"url"` to the image, and they are _not_ encoded. Please clarify.

Comment: not response! I have image, i want search similar images using my script

Comment: Searching for images similar to a given one? No, you cannot. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-ajax-search-api/SF16V7N6DFQ/Cq9Ay4I1KjIJ

Comment: but firefox extension somehow work

Comment: Extensions have permissions, priviledges, and access that webpages do not.

Comment: hmm, what privileges?, my script will be used in the application for Google Chrome

Comment: Probably file reading permissions (eg. submitting an image from disk) etc.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a really old question, but I think that this post here does a good job of explaining what needs to happen:
[Google Image Search How Do I Construct A Reverse Image Search URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584808/google-image-search-how-do-i-construct-a-reverse-image-search-url)