# Perform a Reverse-Image Search in Java?

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I have a rather specific question:

I'm trying to write a program that can look at an image of Pepe the Frog (a meme) and tell you how rare it is. I'm going to measure the rarity based on how many results it gets from a reverse-image search.

The way I'm trying to do it is to have the user browse for an image (I've done this part already using JFileChooser), then perform a reverse-image search on Google and return the number of results. I'd also like to be able to give a percentile result by comparing it to the amount of results from a Google image search for "pepe frog."

The problem is, I have no idea how to do the reverse-image search thing. I'm a bit of a Java noob so sorry if this is a dumb question. I couldn't find the answer to my question online so I decided to ask here.

Comment: this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584808/google-image-search-how-do-i-construct-a-reverse-image-search-url may be helpfull

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997597/google-reverse-image-search-api