# What's this type of encoding?

Tags: urlencode

I'm trying to build application in c# to upload and search images in Google service. I have [this](https://www.google.com.sa/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisitFc56hrSi2zjCe4sR4p2n6_1SLwTo26zZl9ZeYcguiqTFbGXbuYhEsI_1U595_1jmGPDB69m_17l8KjPE-vqRzpkrwLmVMvZ6fvVtDy014lBFf51NaAwRS3ThcfRU-OZkodj5CMUdAY9qQX0XETLskQhq6oTyPueo4AarFG3j2cQ4txmCv6fa_1xOeoYn-4KwNELtH8gpfk4XIgWEDOzUQsOA9jnIgYFTK_1VvaE4jK4VGF_1LUaQQAPcPOmCLTGFXHaoa9A_1W4o8vj7N5SfST0f3HFJHjdzsqq0fVCSiZEcjgfqkRge92GCPX7zDsRVqy7E6zZNoVZOPfuTA5a_1kQTPsvM2QusaXUH6VPZYXWDIsWyWzPnRRD30c4gYgf3l5FAtTV-45P0fqry28BJou8WBsMuQwxFP6ZCJBpNjDVaAgDtNgjA6qeuyyAEVJ6TwY3yAKSeCobtDDXRHqp2-ZQ_1ISYh31-EIt5b0Zv8ldN1-4PY1pJRLCPERExItix4270byixOSmhdewfq5DJYVFoAx96OwwZ6-oX12rNLadhXIJ2UxAfIyGtPdtSg2-VyozMNMyfJwvdvX1zngf63hYdtj8GDfIbKqJ_1qLjaPpveqURfk9JsMo7NYXoeYBAgINHfqye-ZjiuzIPdw3tONCNFSNbsXeyFDpqeB9u9M5Y38TjIqs7-YpGP5JnzE-MgQDBHpMERMzFpcGFkw83z0FQcHZsVq_1R_1PvJz9VTI5wHZZsbMlKljvvL2OMIjfTI4E3v7O5v3hRV_1kQNPH9QPNE3PCtQRq_1v8w12dJC0uDeiPvIHrIGjDdYofJmR5fjkcYT0B32a4ev70-F83zfIT03-GM9OxomNQdLUtgOBfVCXcFNTtPty0-l-P7sSMF1pJbW4aQCUFmKbl0MgPeod2PsIL9guihNzei1V_1IDWEX_1YL6YpCVLZmMnkEM_1SKpEdSAqI69mme5TinuwWTu7blJrMTPqmg4J6AAfp8x9Ig7DmrAaLWD5-onuOgu3IoFHVXTyhHSH7irueYt7l5GvMrH-fMG7IhRUZn6ujKZrlGZZf59cCHCLM0n7SpxgB_1J7KPtlFg1IHebXycFVyB_1xWkUa3KSGk3kitfOkfxhwmvVYe-x-k04kmjVMGaMzaJx-ZoVAcX9j_1UgL7ZKxI-CdZZ78FbpjQfTlMVqcrUKi6npEwAtksfDvb_10bdMxVOXdZHdE5duw3WuL6evNoHdgLD1xFiB2VEnZQzABiP0DAGXEECROFtWZQg84gpM3H8tPRxNPzfPYiHLFdF9j--xreJa5fMsetJedratpZj5CFynxcvGNUgAmzTHxoKJPCxhuS3gkMdo6fBIX4EjuhQXTuQooh96N4_15Q3g6Rxv8fjE0oPeaCMYyu1iqtay3qyXwsX0q0JY_12xHUUfAan535H_16RvwvoVUuy8UULYCbjGolCQqHTVZz-IRi3WcK4RMdsfdk0DdhbijX26k-7UsNphKCVG4V6t1HrNMrNB_1XdA0ZKLIMSINNcGMaUh71yXMkCtj2BvhnKqMYVeqxhVd_12nPx9366_1QRAvzNQSbh3CQTBkMLESiSdxiMos7b2MOgAI8aXIgj_1ggnQQ8pHhy&btnG=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%AB%20%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%B3%D8%A8%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1&hl=ar-SA) link of a search.

**I want to know what encoding this is:**

bi:AMhZZisitFc56hrSi2zjCe4sR4p2n6_1SLwTo26zZl9ZeYcguiqTFbGXbuYhEsI_1U595_1jmGPDB69m_17l8KjPE-vqRzpkrwLmVMvZ6fvVtDy014lBFf51NaAwRS3ThcfRU-OZkodj5CMUdAY9qQX0XETLskQhq6oTyPueo4AarFG3j2cQ4txmCv6fa_1xOeoYn-4KwNELtH8gpfk4XIgWEDOzUQsOA9jnIgYFTK_1VvaE4jK4VGF_1LUaQQAPcPOmCLTGFXHaoa9A_1W4o8vj7N5SfST0f3HFJHjdzsqq0fVCSiZEcjgfqkRge92GCPX7zDsRVqy7E6zZNoVZOPfuTA5a_1kQTPsvM2QusaXUH6VPZYXWDIsWyWzPnRRD30c4gYgf3l5FAtTV-45P0fqry28BJou8WBsMuQwxFP6ZCJBpNjDVaAgDtNgjA6qeuyyAEVJ6TwY3yAKSeCobtDDXRHqp2-ZQ_1ISYh31-EIt5b0Zv8ldN1-4PY1pJRLCPERExItix4270byixOSmhdewfq5DJYVFoAx96OwwZ6-oX12rNLadhXIJ2UxAfIyGtPdtSg2-VyozMNMyfJwvdvX1zngf63hYdtj8GDfIbKqJ_1qLjaPpveqURfk9JsMo7NYXoeYBAgINHfqye-ZjiuzIPdw3tONCNFSNbsXeyFDpqeB9u9M5Y38TjIqs7-YpGP5JnzE-MgQDBHpMERMzFpcGFkw83z0FQcHZsVq_1R_1PvJz9VTI5wHZZsbMlKljvvL2OMIjfTI4E3v7O5v3hRV_1kQNPH9QPNE3PCtQRq_1v8w12dJC0uDeiPvIHrIGjDdYofJmR5fjkcYT0B32a4ev70-F83zfIT03-GM9OxomNQdLUtgOBfVCXcFNTtPty0-l-P7sSMF1pJbW4aQCUFmKbl0MgPeod2PsIL9guihNzei1V_1IDWEX_1YL6YpCVLZmMnkEM_1SKpEdSAqI69mme5TinuwWTu7blJrMTPqmg4J6AAfp8x9Ig7DmrAaLWD5-onuOgu3IoFHVXTyhHSH7irueYt7l5GvMrH-fMG7IhRUZn6ujKZrlGZZf59cCHCLM0n7SpxgB_1J7KPtlFg1IHebXycFVyB_1xWkUa3KSGk3kitfOkfxhwmvVYe-x-k04kmjVMGaMzaJx-ZoVAcX9j_1UgL7ZKxI-CdZZ78FbpjQfTlMVqcrUKi6npEwAtksfDvb_10bdMxVOXdZHdE5duw3WuL6evNoHdgLD1xFiB2VEnZQzABiP0DAGXEECROFtWZQg84gpM3H8tPRxNPzfPYiHLFdF9j--xreJa5fMsetJedratpZj5CFynxcvGNUgAmzTHxoKJPCxhuS3gkMdo6fBIX4EjuhQXTuQooh96N4_15Q3g6Rxv8fjE0oPeaCMYyu1iqtay3qyXwsX0q0JY_12xHUUfAan535H_16RvwvoVUuy8UULYCbjGolCQqHTVZz-IRi3WcK4RMdsfdk0DdhbijX26k-7UsNphKCVG4V6t1HrNMrNB_1XdA0ZKLIMSINNcGMaUh71yXMkCtj2BvhnKqMYVeqxhVd_12nPx9366_1QRAvzNQSb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google image search: How do I construct a reverse image search URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584808/google-image-search-how-do-i-construct-a-reverse-image-search-url)

Comment: But why are you using the front end to build upon? Why don't you use the image search API? This python package has more info: https://github.com/arrrlo/Google-Images-Search Also these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035422/google-image-search-says-api-no-longer-available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part after "sbi:" looks like its is Base64 encoded: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

But if it is supposed to represent the raw bytes of the image then it is hard to confirm . When I decode the example string, that's what I get, raw binary bytes, not a string.

Note: assuming it *is* Base64 then the encoded text continues up-to-and-including the first equal-sign (=) that appears after the "sbi:" in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

@modal_dialog

> But if it is supposed to represent the raw bytes of the image then it
> is hard to confirm . When I decode the example string, that's what I
> get, raw binary bytes, not a string.

However - those binary bytes, the decoded string (taken from the url, up to and including the '='), do not seem to translate to a picture in any known format (not even when adding an extra '=' at the end of the to-be-decoded-string) ... so that seems to me it'd indicate it's ***not*** base64 encoding

[Edit:] @GeeSuth Since your question is related to building your own reverse image search service, you might wanna work with the initial Google Images search url:

**https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=*[location-of-img-to-search-from]***

like eg. *https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?image_url=https://european-made.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/logo-busnises.png1144.png*