# Google Image search in Php

Tags: php, google-image-search

I'm trying to use google images api with PHP, and I'm really not sure what to do.

I have written the following Code

```
<?php
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?".
"v=1.0&q=indian%20institue%20of%20techology";
$jk=file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($jk, true);
echo $json["responseData"]["results"][0]["url"];
?>
```

I wish to find the url of 1st Image from image search.
I'm not getting any result when using the script.

Comment: The 2nd and third line in your code seem to be cut off or broken

Comment: sorry for coping error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has retired the image search API, it is no longer available ([see this SO thread with alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035422/google-image-search-says-api-no-longer-available)).

If you open up the URL you provided it will say this:

```
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "This API is no longer available.", "responseStatus": 403}
```

Comment: Is there a alternate available for searching images through php script ?

Comment: I linked to another Stackoverflow question which lists some alternatives