# How to load google images within my site using api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I am trying to implement [what on this page](http://www.evergreensprinkler.net/plant_finder/google-image-search.html) but I am having this error on console:

> www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAr19Eul_kZsYCBnyMjSJbPhSS8zuUzs-phHbAd9SKTtjFtv728xQ8NcR0mWFbQ0Ita4R2Wzc7rTuWUQ:22
>   A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/?file=search&v=1&output=nocss%3Dtrue, is
>   invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the
>   device has poor network connectivity.

I tried to follow [this SO answers on Google image search says api no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035422/google-image-search-says-api-no-longer-available).

I am basically trying to display images based on a given string using jquery or javascript and ajax.

> **NOTE:** I already set up my own key and cx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this API is no longer available and you won't be able to use it anymore. However, we still have some options:

1. As you may have stated, `Google Custom Search` is the best option. Indeed, you cannot use it with the JS code you have. Once you already have the `App Key` and `cx code` in hands, the only thing you have to do is call the request with the proper params as well as handling the response. Let's see:

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=java&cx=YOUR_CX_CODE&key=YOUR_APP_KEY&num=1&start=99
   ```

   This is going to return the JSON-based response with all the image URLs wrapped onto `cse_image` property. Go ahead, call it by Ajax requests and map the responses to your HTML.

   Also, it is possible to [build the URL dinamically through forms by APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list?q=java&cx=017663620470495640824%253A3gyica0r5wy&fileType=jpg&imgSize=large&rights=cc_publicdomain%252C%20cc_attribute%252C%20cc_sharealike&safe=high&start=10&_h=1&).
2. [CX Generator](https://cse.google.com/cse/create/new), by itself, already gives us a generated JS code with pre-formatted HTML and style for web searching:

   ```
   (function() {
     var cx = 'YOUR_CX_CODE';
     var gcse = document.createElement('script');
     gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
     gcse.async = true;
     gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
   })();

   <gcse:search></gcse:search>
   ```

   ***Note***: Remember that you can add basemaps based on domains, e.g `*.com`, `*.net`, etc. instead of searching only for specific websites.
3. You can explore additional options other than Google ones (once it has a limitation of 100 queries per day for free. After that $5 per 1,000 queries.):

   - Riffsy API: http://api.riffsy.com/#start
   - Gallery Search Imgur API: http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#gallery-search
   - Ababeen API: http://api.ababeen.com/
4. Or, if you still wanna go with Google API, you can try `hubot scripts`, which interacts with the Google Custom Search API for more productivity, once it sets up a lot of things for us: https://github.com/hubot-scripts/hubot-google-images/

Comment: Thanks a lot, check my own answer on how I resolved it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it

```
   $.getJSON( "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_API_KEY&cx=MY_CX_KEY&q=flowers&searchType=image&fileType=jpg&imgSize=xlarge&alt=json",
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){    
               $("body").append("<img src=" + item.link + ">");
            });
    });
```