# java search google image - error 302 - The document has moved

Tags: java, google-search

i have a problem when trying to do a google search from Java.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&as_filetype=jpg&start=0&num=5&q=booba&client=google-csbe&cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

the result is like this:

```
302 Moved
The document has moved
```

could somebody help me please?

thanks

Comment: What do the rest of the response headers look like?

Comment: hi, thank you, this is the rest of the message:    <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://cse.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&amp;as_filetype=jpg&amp;start=0&amp;num=5&amp;q=booba&amp;client=google-csbe&amp;cx=xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

Answer (score 2):

This is how Google is choosing to redirect you to a different URL.  The 'raw' HTTP response will look something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 01 May 2017 20:51:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://cse.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&amp;as_filetype=jpg&amp;start=0&amp;num=5&amp;q=booba&amp;client=google-csbe&amp;cx=xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 325

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

The key here is that `Location` header which indicates the new URL.  Java's `URLConnection` *should* follow the redirect automatically.  However, this is not the case when the redirect would upgrade the connection [from HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884230/urlconnection-doesnt-follow-redirect) (as it does here).

You should either initiate the connection securely using HTTPS, or parse out the `Location` header from each 302 response and create a new connection to that URL.

Comment: i tried to initiate the connection with https. now i have an IOException java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://cse.google.com/

Comment: Can you post a gist or pastebin of the entire raw response (like I quoted in the answer)?

Comment: thank you, i have no more response, now i only have an IO exception :sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) the exception is thrown by this line : connection.getInputStream(),

Comment: if i do it directly on google,i have this result:<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title> it seems that my request is not correct

Comment: Okay, come back if it still doesn't work once your request is correct

Comment: hello, my request is now correct according to google API  but now i have a response 400 with absolutely nothing written,neither in my console and in google directly, blank page:https://www.google.com/cse?searchtype=image&start=0&num=5&q=monkey&as_filetype=png&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx

Comment: i changed my request, now, i have a 403 error:                    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}

Comment: Your new 403 error has the reason right there in the response: `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup`

Answer (score 0):

i changed my request, now, i have a 403 error:

```
{ "error": { "errors": [ {
 "domain": "usageLimits", 
 "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", 
 "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use  requires signup.",
 "extendedHelp": "code.google.com/apis/console"; } ], 
 "code": 403, "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded
```

it could be a problem caused by the google server Key that i should get in the console for developper of google, BUT it is impossible to access the console, it gives me a blank page when i try to go there:

https://console.developers.google.com/project

do you know why?

Comment: The link you provided works fine for me, albeit on mobile. Try the usual suspects: clear cache and cookies, restart your browser, etc

Comment: thank you, the problem was the chrome navigator, i am on XP and it is not updated any more

Answer (score 0):

ok,
i found the answer, to use custom search, you need to have a cx value And a key value wich you can get https://console.developers.google.com/
For your request to work, you also need to put the start parameter at minimum 1, because 0 gives you an error 400 invalid value

this post helped me a lot:

[Google image search says api no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035422/google-image-search-says-api-no-longer-available)

and this is my request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=xxxxxxx&searchtype=image&start=1&num=5&q=monkey&as_filetype=png&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=xxxxxx
```