# Search Image in google

Tags: c#, image, google-chrome, picturebox

I need to search in google images for a photo and to take the first result and to put in picturebox.
The search is by a string that the user is picking.
please help.
I am Using c#

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally we find that questions with some code in them help us to understand where you are at in your problem solving, and where specifically we can be helpful. You are more likely to get helpful answers if you can be as specific as possible in your question. For example, if you already have code capable of running the search, but are having trouble scraping the image out of the results, then we might be able to offer better advice on what to try next. Or, if you aren't sure how to run an HTTP query, then that would imply very different advice.

Answer (score 0):

To hit the Google Image API from your c# code, you will need to perform an HTTP post request. I believe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176538/net-httpclient-how-to-post-string-value) can show you how to format your request.

Also, it appears that the Google Image API is deprecated and will no longer work soon, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035422/google-image-search-says-api-no-longer-available).