# How to integrate google image search into my app?

Tags: javascript, html, image, search, web-scraping

I am trying to build an app that can take an input image and look for similar images with Google's image search engine.Then on the base of similar images information it can give me information about what is on that input picture.

The question though is how to use Google's image search engine on my app and get all similar images and their information in response with JSON ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34035422/google-image-search-says-api-no-longer-available

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Vision Api to detect details about images..
Enter following link to know how to use google vision Api 
=>
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.infoworld.com/article/3269367/how-to-use-the-google-vision-api.amp.html

......

Comment: That is nice thing but it's not what i am searching.Likely i need some scraping tools.