# Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#, exception

I have a C# program that takes a URL and downloads the images off the website to the users computer.The program seems to work fine until about the 21st image and then it encounters and error(https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1hyW.png). I'm not sure why this is happening.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 0;
    GrantAccess("C:\\My kitty collection");
    for (int i = 0; i > -1 ; i++)
    {
        FindSrc();
        num++;
        Console.WriteLine("src number" + num.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(pah);
        try
        {
            SaveImage(pah + "\\kitty" + num.ToString() + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg, src);
        }
        catch (ExternalException)
        {
            //Something is wrong with Format -- Maybe required Format is not
            // applicable here
            Console.WriteLine("Error:Wrong Format");
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Stream is bad");
            //Something wrong with Stream
        }
    }
}

//this method finds the img source
public static void FindSrc()
{
    string url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=kitty&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix57KhhbHjAhWSB80KHa21BL8Q_AUIECgB&biw=1920&bih=920";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string html = code(url);
    int beg = html.Substring(start).IndexOf("img height")+start;
    int mid = html.Substring(beg).IndexOf("src");
    int end = html.Substring(beg + mid + 5).IndexOf("\"");
    src = html.Substring(beg + mid + 5, end);
    start = beg + mid + 5 + end;
    Console.WriteLine(src);
}

//this method downloads the image given the source, path, and format.
public static void SaveImage(string filename, ImageFormat format, string imageUrl)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Stream stream = client.OpenRead(imageUrl);
    Bitmap bitmap; bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
    if (bitmap != null)
        bitmap.Save(filename, format);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
    client.Dispose();
}

//this method creates a folder and give writing permissions 
public static void GrantAccess(string file)
{
    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(file);
    if (!exists)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(file);
        pah = di.FullName;
        Console.WriteLine("The Folder is created Sucessfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Folder already exists");
    }

    DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(file);
    DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
    dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
    dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
}

}

}
```

I expected the program to continue to download images until it was closed, but instead it gave me the error "Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException"

Comment: Dominick, its not your appplication/program, its the website, it seems to be a redirect or bot/crawler detection.

try adding a delay between downloads, like maybe 1-3 seconds

Comment: thanks @DocMax for the formatting

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help.

Comment: Dominick, since you are using google search engine, to crawl  for images, you are getting the last image which is actually a javascript item which queries google for the next set of 20 images. google loads images 20 at a time, in a continues list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now You can search images with Custom image search API.
Go to - https://cse.google.com/cse/all

ref:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34062436/6651840