# How to post reverse google search image with base64

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-image-search

I have problem how to parameters to post base64 to reverse google search image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [blog](http://www.techfug.com/2015/11/google-reverse-image-search-on-mobile.html) on how to do Reverse Google Image Search. It shows here what steps you need to do.

It shows here that it uses the standard HTML5 File System APIs. Internally, it takes your image file, converts it to Base64 (data URI) and submit the encoded image as HTTP POST request to Google Image. The browser then automatically redirects to the search page.

You can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584808/google-image-search-how-do-i-construct-a-reverse-image-search-url) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but i dont know what is parameters that filled base64 to submit POST